# Why when compiling my program the file i created could not be opened?

Tags: c

I have made a program trying to get data from users such as account number name balance and credit limit.There is an option if the user is new or not.If the user its new it has the option to create a new record for them.At the end when i try runing the program the file that ive created does not want to open.
`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct clientData{
char name[20];
int accNum;
float balance;
float limit;
};

void print(FILE *fPtr) {
rewind(fPtr);
struct clientData client={"",0,0.0,0.0};
printf("%-35s %-20s %-20s %-20s\n","NAME","ACCOUNT#","BALANCE","CREDIT LIMIT");
while(fread(&client,sizeof(struct clientData),1,fPtr) && !feof(fPtr)){
    if(client.accNum!=0)
        printf("%-35s %-20d %-20.2f %-20.2f\n",client.name,client.accNum,client.balance,client.limit);
}
}

int checkExist(FILE *fPtr,struct clientData client){
struct clientData temp;
fseek(fPtr,(client.accNum/50-1)*sizeof(struct clientData),SEEK_SET);
fread(&temp,sizeof(struct clientData),1,fPtr);
if(temp.accNum==client.accNum)
    return 1;
return 0;
}

int checkName(char name[]){
int i;
for(i=0;i<strlen(name);i++){
    name[i]=toupper(name[i]);
    if(!(name[i]>='A' && name[i]<='Z' || name[i]==' '))
        return 0;
}
 return 1;
}
void findName(char name[]){
printf("ENTER CUSTOMER NAME\n");
getchar();
fgets(name,30,stdin);
name[strlen(name)-1]='\0';
while(!checkName(name)){
    printf("RE-ENTER CUSTOMER NAME.\n");
    getchar();
    fgets(name,30,stdin);
    name[strlen(name)-1]='\0';
}
}

void checkLimit(float *limitNum){
while(*limitNum<0){
    printf("RE-ENTER CUSTOMER CREDIT LIMIT.\n");
    scanf("%f",limitNum);
    }
}

void newRecord(FILE *fPtr,struct clientData client){
if(!checkExist(fPtr,client)){
    findName(client.name);
    printf("ENTER CUSTOMER CREDIT LIMIT\n");
    scanf("%f",&client.limit);
    checkLimit(&client.limit);
    if(client.balance<=client.limit || client.limit==0){

        printf("DEAR %s\n"
               "THANK YOU FOR YOUR BUSINESS\n",client.name);
            fseek(fPtr,(client.accNum/50-1)*sizeof(struct clientData),SEEK_SET);
              fwrite(&client,sizeof(struct clientData),1,fPtr);
    }
    else
        printf("Dear %s\n"
                       " WE CANNOT AUTHORIZE THIS PURCHASE AT THIS TIME AS IT\n"
                           "WOULD PUT YOU %.2f EURO OVER YOUR CREDIT LIMIT.\n",client.name,(client.balance));

}
else printf("ACCOUNT ALREADY EXISTS - RE ENTER DATA.\n");
}
void modifyRec(FILE *fPtr,struct clientData client){

             double new_balance;
             if(checkExist(fPtr,client)){
                new_balance=client.balance;
                fseek(fPtr,(client.accNum/50-1)*sizeof(struct clientData),SEEK_SET);
                fread(&client,sizeof(struct clientData),1,fPtr);
                if(client.balance<=client.limit || client.limit==0){

                    printf("DEAR %s\n"

               "THANK YOU FOR THE BUSINESS.\n",client.name);
                    fseek(fPtr,(client.accNum/50-1)*sizeof(struct clientData),SEEK_SET);
                    fwrite(&client,sizeof(struct clientData),1,fPtr);
                }else
                printf("Dear %s\n"
                       " WE CANNOT AUTHORIZE THIS PURCHASE AT THIS TIME AS IT\n"
                           "WOULD PUT YOU %.2f EURO OVER YOUR CREDIT LIMIT.\n",client.name,(client.balance));


             }else {
             printf("ACCOUNT DOES NOT EXIST - RE ENTER DATA.\n");

}

}
void checkAccNum(int *accountNumber){
while(*accountNumber%50!=0 && *accountNumber>0){
    printf("RE ENTER ACCOUNT NUMBER.\n");
    scanf("%d",accountNumber);
}
}
void checkBalance(float *balanceNum){
while(*balanceNum<0){
    printf("RE ENTER BALANCE.\n");
    scanf("%f",balanceNum);
  }
 }
void check(FILE *readPtr)
{
    struct clientData client={"",0,0.0,0.0};
    char answer;
    printf("ENTER ACCOUNT NUMBER\n");
    scanf("%d",&client.accNum);
    checkAccNum(&client.accNum);

        while(client.accNum>0){
            printf("ENTER AMOUNT OF PURCHASE\n");
            scanf("%f",&client.balance);
            checkBalance(&client.balance);
            printf("IS THIS A NEW ACCOUNT NUMBER?(Y OR N):\n");
            getchar();
            scanf("%c",&answer);
            if(answer=='N'){
              modifyRec(readPtr,client);
            }
          else
            if(answer=='Y'){
             newRecord(readPtr,client);
          }
          printf("ENTER ACCOUNT NUMBER\n");
          scanf("%d",&client.accNum);
        }
    }




int main()
{
    FILE *fPtr;
    if((fPtr=fopen("ACCT.txt","r+"))==NULL)
        printf("File could not be opened.\n");
    else {
        print(fPtr);
        check(fPtr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`
[theoutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkuRA.png)

I have made an if else statement to check if the file is open and from what you can see the file doesnt open itself in order for the program to run.

Comment: ACCT.txt should be in the same directory with your exe file

Comment: Use `perror` to get a more useful explanation of why `fopen` failed.